# Return query with total rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a way to return data out of the database AND counting the rows I selected. I tried a few things I found, but they or ended up in an error, or are just not working fully.

Let me explain the following code. I'm getting data from a certain table called 'posts' where the images table will be joined to the posts table. If the $category parameter along with the $start and $limit parameters are filled in, it jumps the else to select posts with a certain type only.(type_bericht).

```
function get($table, $category = null, $start = null, $limit = null, $conn) {
    if (!$category) {
        $query = $conn->query(
                  "SELECT $table.*, COUNT($table.id)
                   AS post_count, images.id AS imageid, images.url AS iurl
                   FROM $table
                   LEFT JOIN images ON images.id = $table.image_id
                   ORDER BY id DESC");
    } else {
        $query = $conn->query(
                   "SELECT $table.*, COUNT($table.id)
                    AS post_count, images.id AS imageid, images.url AS iurl
                    FROM $table
                    LEFT JOIN images ON images.id = $table.image_id    
                    WHERE type_bericht = '$category'
                    ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");

    }

    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't work fully. It counts and returns (a number) the posts which are selected from the database, but it only shows one single row out of the table. If I remove the "COUNT($table.id) AS post_count" part, it shows all the posts normally again, but I dont want that. Does somebody understand what I might forget or not doing right?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Marciano, it wouldn't hurt to put the query strings on a separate line, so that readers wouldn't have to scroll as much.

Answer (score 0):

use `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS $table.* ...` (add "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" after each SELECT directly) and then use `$db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS();")` to get the counts.

Answer (score 0):

Could not remove the Count() part of the sql statement and then use:

```
if (count($query) > 0) {
    return $query;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Or is $query not an array?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you `COUNT()` it will implicitly group everything together.

Assuming you use MySQL you can use the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` flag like:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM ...
```

to let MySQL store the total number of results. You can then retrieve that number by executing a second query immediately afterwards:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS rowcount
```

which behaves like a normal select query. It will return one row with one column called `rowcount` which stores the total number of found rows from the previous query.

Comment: But how can I return 2 results in that function? The query itself and the row count?

Comment: @Marciano You don't. You have to execute them as two completely seperate queries.